# migrate Cassandra2 cluster to a new Cassandra3 cluster, same schema, zero downtime

Tags: database, cassandra, synchronization, migrate

Currently i'm running on multi node dc with Cassandra 2.0.11
I have a new multi node DC running Cassandra 3.1.11
I want to migrate all data with zero downtime and zero data loss
I have nonstop read's/write's

1: i thought about connecting the DC's to same cluster and let Cassandra do what it know to do and then slowly decommission old dc but I have read I cannot(?) have different Cassandra version on same cluster

2: i could have same Cassandra version, connect DC to cluster,
have data migrate'd and then upgrade from 2.0.11=>...=>3.1.11
this is not an option at this point.

any advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, Spark Cassandra Connector for example (full code is [in the documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connecting-to-multiple-cassandra-clusters)).

```
  val rddFromClusterOne = {
    // Sets connectorToClusterOne as default connection for everything in this code block
    implicit val c = connectorToClusterOne
    sc.cassandraTable("ks","tab")
  }

  {
    //Sets connectorToClusterTwo as the default connection for everything in this code block
    implicit val c = connectorToClusterTwo
    rddFromClusterOne.saveToCassandra("ks","tab")
  }
```

But you also need to modify your application to write to both clusters for a some period of time, until data is copied from one cluster to another, and after data is copied, you can switch read operations to new cluster.

Comment: I can change my client to write to both cluster, thats not a problem.
thing is, when i read data from ClusterA and write it to ClusterB
ClusterB might have already gotten that data or it might have not written it yet.. so after i copy from ClusterA then the client write to ClusterB the same data (we sum it up for example..) then the result would be wrong.
hope i made myself clear enough

Comment: This is of course depends on your application, but your application need to get decision on the data read from Cluster A. After that - when you're writing data, your will overwrite the data with the same primary key

Comment: i'm not sure i understood %100.. 
But we update the row, not writing and forgetting

Comment: You may use `QUORUM` for data reading, in this case new data should be sent to another cluster in case if they are changing